# An estimate for the Benjamin-Ono equation from T. Tao's well-posedness paper

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

In https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307289  (eq. (8)),
for a (smooth) solution of the equation $$u_t - uu_x +  Hu_{xx}  = 0$$ ​
(where $H$ denotes the Hilbert transform) the following estimate is stated (without computations):
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb R} (u_x^2 -\frac{3}{4} u^2 H u_x - \frac{1}{8} u^4 )dx = 0$$
I've tried to reproduce it, but I get extra terms that don't cancel out. How does one work out this estimate?

Bonus question: is it true/clear that $(u_x^2 -\frac{3}{4} u^2 H u_x - \frac{1}{8} u^4 )$ is nonnegative and/or that the estimate above is enough to bound $\|u\|_{L^4}$ in terms of the $L^4$ and $H^1$ norm of the initial data?